# How to bind ListView in a TabControl in xaml and .cs file

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created a TabControl and there is a ListView. I am trying to bind the list created in .cs file for the same window , but the list is not getting reflected int he xaml file while binding.

I have tried create a tab with name "List view" and bind ListViewItems created in .cs file.

I have also tried to bind the text in textblock but it did not reflect.

Code-behind

```
namespace Shweta
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window5.xaml
    ///// </summary>
    public partial class Window5 : Window
    {
        public Window5()
        {            
             InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class CollectionViewModel
    {
      public List<string> ListViewItems
        {
            get
            {
                return new List<string>
                {
                    "First name",
                    "Second name",
                    "Third name"
                };
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Xaml markup

```
<Window x:Class="Shweta.Window5"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window5" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="238*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="47*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="214*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <TabControl>
                <TabItem Header="List View">
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListViewItems}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <Border Background="LightBlue" Padding="3"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: you need to set DataContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings to view model will work if `DataContext` is set with a view model object:

```
public Window5()
{            
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = new CollectionViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Yes sure, Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: @shweta, it is explained in [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (I suggest you take a look at it): there should be a checkmark on the left side of the answer under score counter :) when inactive it is gray, when checked - green